# Import external txt with phyton

Tags: animation

Guys I'm trying to import an external .txt file with some paragraphs, I know I will have a lot of work ahead of me to split that file into the texts I already have animation.

But for the moment how can I import an external .txt that is in the same folder as the .blend and replace the content from the text object that has already an animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I am using Blender 2.81a)

````
import bpy
import os

# This gets text from file
filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(bpy.data.filepath), "info.txt")
f = open(filename, "r")
text_data = f.read()
f.close()

# Get your text object (object name here is 'Text')
obj = bpy.data.objects['Text']
obj.data.body = text_data # set text

```
````